# How can I modify multiple records at once using samw Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, I need to update n records at once in same form (each record have your date field to update). To do this, I'm trying to use this def:

```
 def marcado 
    set_previsao
    confs = @previsao.previtems.where(status: "Confirmado").index_by{|previtem| previtem[:id]}
     confs.each do |id, attributes|
      previtem = @previsao.previtems.find(id)
      previtem.update(attributes)
   end
```

Doing this, it returns this error message:

ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Since that confs variable is a hash.

In addition, if I do this way:

```
def marcado 
    set_previsao
    confs = @previsao.previtems.where(status: "Confirmado").pluck(:id).map { |id| [id, {status: "Marcado", data_marcacao: params[:data_marcacao]}] }.to_h
     confs.each do |id, attributes|
      previtem = @previsao.previtems.find(id)
      previtem.update(attributes)
   end
```

With the lines of previous def, all records are saved with last record value.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: if you just wish to update the updated_at attribute: `@previsao.previtems.where(status: "Confirmado").update_all(updated_at: DateTime.now)`. Have I correctly understood what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely you're not taking advantage of some rails features.  And you have not really given enough information to supply the best suggestion.

If all these records belong to some master record then you should investigate

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

If they are not related to some master record then you might look into

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert